# How do I convert all property values in an object to type string?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working with an object containing properties with values that are either type string or type number. Some properties are nested objects, and these nested objects also contain properties with values that could be either type string or type number. Take the following object as a simplified example:

```
var myObj = {
  myProp1: 'bed',
  myProp2: 10,
  myProp3: {
    myNestedProp1: 'desk',
    myNestedProp2: 20
  }
};
```

I want all of these values to be type string, so any values that are type number will need to be converted.

What is the most efficient approach to achieving this?

I've tried using for..in and also played around with Object.keys, but was unsuccessful. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: @asw1984, it's working for you ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Object.keys should be fine, you just need to use recursion when you find nested objects. To cast something to string, you can simply use this trick

```
var str = '' + val;
```

```js
var myObj = {
  myProp1: 'bed',
  myProp2: 10,
  myProp3: {
    myNestedProp1: 'desk',
    myNestedProp2: 20
  }
};

function toString(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      return toString(o[k]);
    }
    
    o[k] = '' + o[k];
  });
  
  return o;
}

console.log(toString(myObj));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. What about a scenario where the data isn't an object, but an array of objects, each needing the same treatment as the object above? Wrapping the forEach in another forEach seems inefficient form a performance standpoint. Perhaps there's a better way to account for the array of objects?

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue, it converts entire object or nested objects which can have arrays, also added one more property to check if property is null then it fails so added,
`!isNullOrUndefined(object[k])`

Comment: What about mutability? This method seems to mutate the original object which may cause issues in some circumstances. How do you implement it without mutating the original one?
I've trying to make a deep copy of an original object using lodash cloneDeep, but unfortunately, nested object keys were not converted.

Comment: You could clone the input object first, then pass the clone to `toString` method.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `recursive` method which looks through all the `keys`.

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own **enumerable** properties.

There are two cases:

- if `typeof` operator returns `object`, then you have to **recall** the function.
- otherwise, you just need to apply `String()` method.

But you can use `ternary` operator for `one-line` solution.

```
 typeof myObj[key] == 'object' ? replace(myObj[key]) : myObj[key]= myObj[key].toString();
```

```js
var myObj = {
  myProp1: 'bed',
  myProp2: 10,
  myProp3: {
    myNestedProp1: 'desk',
    myNestedProp2: 20
  }
};
function replace(myObj){
  Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key){
    typeof myObj[key] == 'object' ? replace(myObj[key]) : myObj[key]= String(myObj[key]);
  });
}
replace(myObj);
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Side note: Calling `toString()` works fine in this case if there are only strings and numbers, but it would fail if the values could also be `null` or `undefined`. For these cases, `String(value)` or `'' + value` would work.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, that's true. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what was asked, but it can be useful. Implementation with [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 25,
  address: {
    street: 'Green',
    houseNumber: 11
  },
  verified: true,
  bio: null,
  createdAt: NaN
};

function convertValuesToStringsDeep(obj) {
  return _.cloneDeepWith(obj, value => {
    return !_.isPlainObject(value) ? _.toString(value) : undefined;
  });
}

const copy = convertValuesToStringsDeep(person);
console.log(copy);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Object copy will be:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "25",
  "address": {
    "street": "Green",
    "houseNumber": "11"
  },
  "verified": "true",
  "bio": "",
  "createdAt": "NaN"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `cloneDeepWith` function.

> **Note:** Apparently [`cloneDeepWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeepWith) function is available in npm for nodejs only.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

var myObj = {
  myProp1: 'bed',
  myProp2: 10,
  myProp3: {
    myNestedProp1: 'desk',
    myNestedProp2: 20
  }
};

function toString(obj) {
    return _.cloneDeepWith(obj, val => val.toString());
}

console.log(toString(myObj));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - care to link to a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Apparently cloneDeepWith function is available in npm for nodejs only.

Answer (score 0):

After loop all object keys like @martin-adámek and @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut mentioned above,
you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to cast property values in an object to type string. It looks more friendly:

```js
obj[key] = `${obj[key]}`
```

Answer (score -5):

Use the toString() method; [mozilla reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

```
var myObj = {
  myProp1: 'bed',
  myProp2: (10).toString(),
  myProp3: {
    myNestedProp1: 'desk',
    myNestedProp2: (20).toString()
  }
};
```

Comment: (1) This isn't valid syntax (it needs to have two periods) and (2) I think the OP is asking how to do this using an already-created `myObj` -- otherwise, why not just put the numbers in quotes instead of doing `.toString()`?

Comment: I see, then should we use `myObj.toString()` ?

Comment: It seems like the OP wants to iterate over all properties and sub-properties (and so on recursively) of the object and convert them to strings.